# is too much services in symfony will slow down its performance?

Tags: performance, soa, symfony-2.4

Hi i am new to the service oriented architecture world. can some one please tell me is too much service creation will slow down the performance of symfony2 framework based project?

Comment: Performance more depends on what you are doing/implementing than on the number of services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i found one solution to over come when we require too many services and if those services is going to slow down your performance than use lazy loading services.

For more reference see this link http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/lazy_services.html